# Angular slide down and up animation

Tags: angular

I try to make a simple slide up and down animation in Angular but i have a problem.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="width: 228px">
  <a href="#" (click)=onDropDown()>
    <h3>Label</h3>
  </a>
  <ul [@dropDown]="state" class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<hr [@slideUpDown]='state'>
```

and my TypeScript file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate, keyframes } from '@angular/animations';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('dropDown', [
      state('hide', style({
        display: 'none',
        opacity: 0
      })),
      state('show', style({
        display: 'block',
        opacity: 1
      })),
      transition('hide => show', animate('300ms ease-out')),
      transition('show => hide', animate('300ms ease-in'))
    ]),
    trigger('slideUpDown', [
      state('hide', style({
        transform: 'translateY(0)'
      })),
      state('show', style({
        transform: 'translateY(0)'
      })),
      transition('hide => show', animate('300ms ease-out')),
      transition('show => hide', animate('300ms ease-in'))
    ]),
  ]
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

  state = 'hide';

  constructor() {  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onDropDown(){
    this.state == 'hide' ? this.state = 'show' : this.state = 'hide';
  }
}
```

The way that my  shows is ok for me.
The problem is that I want to animate the horizontal line but since it's stil in one position i can't animate it with the transform property.

How can I make it slide up and down smooth?

Should I close it in one div and animate the hight of the parent div?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `since it's stil in one position i can't animate it with the transform property` ?

Comment: I mean that transformY(*px) won't work

Comment: That's because you're not supposed to do it like that. Let me make an answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Following your comments*

When you create an animation the way you did, you declare **states** : states are ... Well, states (duh), that will be applied to the elements on the given condition.

So when you write this

```
state('hide', style({
  transform: 'translateY(0)'
}))
```

You mean

> My component should not be translated on the Y axis when my variable is equal to `hide`

This means that you can write your states like this

```
  state('hide', style({
    transform: 'translateY(100vh)'
  })),
  state('show', style({
    transform: 'translateY(0)'
  })),
```

the element will leave the window when asked to hide, and will come back when asked to show.

And if you already have a value on the transform, then let Angular handle it

```
  state('hide', style({
    transform: 'translateY(100vh)'
  })),
  state('show', style({
    transform: '*'
  })),
```

Comment: I don't know if I made something wrong but that doesn't work like I wanted to. I made it like this now: 
trigger('slideUpDown', [
      state('hide', style({
        height: '31px'
      })),
      state('show', style({
        height: '144px'
      })),
      transition('hide => show', animate('300ms ease-out')),
      transition('show => hide', animate('300ms ease-in'))
    ]),
but how to start the dropDown trigger after the slideUpDown ends?

Comment: You have two choices : use the `query` operator (this give orders to your animations, but it's tidious to implement), or calculate the duration (or use variables) of your first animation, and add this delay to your second animation (syntax: `animate [duration] [delay] [easing function]`)

Comment: Tried again your solution but can it work like accordion?

Comment: Of course ir can, that's just up to you. When you're a beginner, you have to practice to discover the animations in Angular, but once you do it, it works like a charm.